# Finding height from voltage

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm using a 45" fuel rod which gives a reading of 0 - 5 volts depending on where the float sensor is on it. At the bottom the fuel rod reads 0, at the top it reads 5 and in the middle it reads 2.5.

I'm wondering what formula can be used to get the height for any given voltage? Initially I had used

> (45/5) * voltage

but I don't think that formula is quite right.

Note:Not homework, but homework is the closest tag I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

You have it exactly right.  Your data supports that the readout is linear.  It would be better to show the units:  $\text{height (inches)} = \frac {\text V_{\text{out}} \text{(volts)}}{5 \text{volts}} \text{45 inches}=9 \frac{\text {volts}}{\text{inch}}\text V_{\text{out}} \text{(volts)}$.  Voltages are (usually) measured in volts, but heights can be in many units.